# Exrtact result just to the end of the line/row

Tags: regex, list, line

I am using this  `(?<=Postcode:).*` Which works perfectly except it also includes text from the following  list(li) how can I change this to include just the line where "postcode" is found.

Comment: how does the input text look like? what information do you want to match/extract?

Comment: What regex engine do you use, does the dot match newlines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
(?<=Postcode:)[\w\s]*
```

This will match all alphanumeric characters and spaces following `Postcode:`.  It will stop when it finds something else  (for example, a `<li>` tag, which I assume is what you meant by "the following list").

Explanation: this portion of the regex `[...]` is a character class.  It will match anything in the collection of characters contained inside.  In the above example, it matches any number of alphanumeric characters and spaces.  If you also want to match, say, `-` and `.`, you could edit it like this:

```
(?<=Postcode:)[\w\s\-\.]*
```

Note that `-` and `.` had to be escaped because they are both special characters: `.` matches any character, and `-` within a character class is used for ranges, such as `[a-h0-9]`.

Comment: That's cool, I was hoping for something generic that I could adapt. The code has worked perfectly. I used it for County, Telephone, Country, Grid reference without an issue. Only 1 issue I had was when it came to latitude which has 50.33445 - -3.444678 and found it returned on 50 stopping at the point. Shall I open another question for this?

Comment: @AndrewPerry, I updated the answer to help with that problem, as well as to explain a bit more of what is going on.

Comment: dan the SuperMan - works a treat and the explanation is a eureka moment for me! Thanks again